# how to set initial value of table view cell property in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an image property on my table view cell.  I want to populate this image to an image.

My cell looks like:

```
//.h
@interface GAFriendStatusTableViewCell : PFTableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *friendImage;

@end

//.m
#import "GAFriendStatusTableViewCell.h"

@implementation GAFriendStatusTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.friendImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

@end
```

This doesn't set the image.  How can I set the image for this cell within the cell class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your image view is an IBOutlet, I'm assuming you've got your cell layout defined in a .xib or storyboard. That being the case, your initialization code should go in the `awakeFromNib` method. This is the method that is called when the cell is created from the nib. That's why the `//Initialization code` comment is there. `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` is never called in this scenario, which is why your image is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Otherwise if you have a Nib or Storyboard you're using then set the default in the prototype cell you are using.